# When does the event 'MyBase.Load' fire?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm working with the following bit of code to invoke a dialog.

```
Using frmSomeForm As New SomeForm()
    frmSomeForm.intSomeVariable = 6
    frmSomeForm.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

Inside that `SomeForm()` is a `MyBase.Load` event. In this particular case:

```
Private Sub SomeForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If intSomeVariable <> 0 Then SomeOtherSub()
End Sub
```

My question is when does the load event fire? Does it fire at the moment the `.ShowDialog()` is invoked or is it fired at the moment of the `Using` line.

Comment: [Form.Load Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) : `Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.` you might want to pass `intSomeVariable` as a ctor parameter if it is required that it have that value.

Comment: Got it. Would a Property also work in this case?

Comment: Is what you have not working?

Comment: It currently is but I always get mixed results about using .Load events hence why I was trying to determine exactly when does .Load actually fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Load` event is only raised once you call `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`, when the form is about to be shown. Currently your `frmSomeForm.intSomeVariable = 6` line **will always** fire before the `Load` event.

**Answering your comment *`"Would a Property also work in this case?"`*:**

Keep in mind that any code that you put *before* your `Show()` or `ShowDialog()` call will be executed first, even if it's a time consuming one. Code is executed synchronously line-by-line.

For example, this:

```
TimeConsumingMethod()
frmSomeForm.ShowDialog()
```

would only call `frmSomeForm.ShowDialog()` ***after*** the `TimeConsumingMethod()` has completed successfully, even if that takes for ever.